# Select rows who's FIRST result is a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a custom written analytics system running and I'm trying to write a query that returns users who landed on a specific page as their first hit. The relevant parts of the table is setup as such, with some simple data:

```
pageviews Table
+----+---------------------+----------+-------------+
| id |       time_in       | users_id | articles_id |
+----+---------------------+----------+-------------+
|  0 | 2013-08-15 00:00:00 |        0 |           0 |
|  1 | 2013-08-16 00:00:00 |        0 |           1 |
|  2 | 2013-08-17 00:00:00 |        1 |           1 |
|  3 | 2013-08-18 00:00:00 |        1 |           0 |
|  4 | 2013-08-19 00:00:00 |        1 |           1 |
|  5 | 2013-08-20 00:00:00 |        2 |           1 |
+----+---------------------+----------+-------------+
```

NOTE: The ID fields in my DB are actually using GUIDs, not ints as in this simple example.

Now, if I want to see who read article `1` as their first hit, I want my query to return users `1` and `2`, but not `0`, as user `0` saw article `0` as their first hit on the site. Conversely, if I want to see who read article `0` first, the query would only return user `0`.

Here is my query thus far:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    pageviews
WHERE 
    articles_id = 1
GROUP BY
    users_id
ORDER BY
    time_in
```

But this returns distinct user IDs for all users who've read article `1`, not filtering out the users who did not see it as their first result. I feel like I'm going the wrong direction with my query, so I'm turning towards you guys.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it

```
SELECT v.users_id
  FROM pageviews v JOIN
(
  SELECT users_id, MIN(time_in) time_in
    FROM pageviews
   GROUP BY users_id
) q ON v.users_id = q.users_id AND v.time_in = q.time_in
 WHERE v.articles_id = 1
```

Output:

```
| USERS_ID |
------------
|        1 |
|        2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ddf18/6)** demo

Comment: Thanks! I found this [article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) that not only affirms the functionality of your answer, but also the optimal performance.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
SELECT users_id
FROM pageviews p
WHERE articles_id = 1
AND time_in = (SELECT MIN(time_in) from pageviews p2 WHERE p2.users_id = p.users_id)
```

**[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5346b/20)**